# Jdatechooser text alignement to RIGHT

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jdatechooser

I need to align the text in **Jdatechooser** text field. It always aligns the text(the selected date) to LEFT but i need at RIGHT side.

I have tried this but its not working,

```
StartJCal.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```

The `setTextAlignment` method is not available for Jdatechooser.

```
    StartJCal = new JDateChooser();
    StartJCal.setDateFormatString("yyyyMMdd");
    StartJCal.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    StartJCal.setSize(new Dimension(105, 0));
```

This is the piece of code am using.How can i align the text please help

Comment: which one JDateChooser, for AWT, GWT, JavaFX, SWT or Swing, by default there is (J)Spinner

Comment: @mKorbel its for swing

Comment: I think that there (here are a few versions, by various authors) is JSpinner, search how to align text for this JComponent (see API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StartJCal = new JDateChooser();
JTextFieldDateEditor dateEditor = (JTextFieldDateEditor)StartJCal.getComponent(1);
dateEditor.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
StartJCal.setDateFormatString("yyyyMMdd");
StartJCal.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 11));
StartJCal.setSize(new Dimension(105, 0));
```

try this. it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Similar but not passing through `getComponent()`

```
StartJCal = new JDateChooser();

JTextFieldDateEditor dateEditor = (JTextFieldDateEditor)StartJCal.getDateEditor();
dateEditor.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

StartJCal.setDateFormatString("yyyyMMdd");
StartJCal.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 11));
StartJCal.setSize(new Dimension(105, 0));
```

Comment: Please, use English on SO.